# Change coordinate system of points shown by camera

Tags: python, quaternions

I am working on a product to localise an object relative to another.
I have a Stereoscopic camera that gives me the following data from Rigid bodies (which are linked to the objects I want to localise) with reflective markers on them :

Let's call object1 `A` and object2 `B`
The camera returns those values :
`TxA`, `TyA`, `TzA`, `Q0A`, `QxA`, `QyA`, `QzA`
`TxB`, `TyB`, `TzB`, `Q0B`, `QxB`, `QyB`, `QzB`

The camera software allow you to output `B` values referenced to `A`, but I wanted to recreate this function in my script.

For that, in my script, I then created 2 quaternions such as :

```
QuatA = Quaternion (Q0A, QxA, QyA, QzA)
QuatB = Quaternion (Q0B, QxB, QyB, QzB)
```

I tried to reference `QuatB` to `QuatA` by doing :

```
Result = QuatA * QuatB * QuatA.conj()
```

But the results seem to be different than what the camera software.

For example :

```
QuatA = Quaternion(0.8381, 0.2948, -0.0762, -0.4526)

QuatB = Quaternion(0.6062, -0.2564, -0.6147, -0.4347)
```

```
Results : Quaternion(0.753, 0.241, -0.626, 0.421)

Camera output : 0.676, -0.149, -0.714, 0.111
```

Can anyone help on this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, I found this code that works correctly for me :

```
QuatA = QuatA.conj()
a = ( QuatA.q0 + QuatA.qx ) * ( QuatB.q0 + QuatB.qx)
b = ( QuatA.qz - QuatA.qy ) * ( QuatB.qy - QuatB.qz)
c = ( QuatA.qx - QuatA.q0 ) * ( QuatB.qy + QuatB.qz)
d = ( QuatA.qy + QuatA.qz ) * ( QuatB.qx - QuatB.q0)
e = ( QuatA.qx + QuatA.qz ) * ( QuatB.qx + QuatB.qy)
f = ( QuatA.qx - QuatA.qz ) * ( QuatB.qx - QuatB.qy)
g = ( QuatA.q0 + QuatA.qy ) * ( QuatB.q0 - QuatB.qz)
h = ( QuatA.q0 - QuatA.qy ) * ( QuatB.q0 + QuatB.qz)


rotatedq0 = b + ( -e - f + g + h ) / 2
rotatedqx = a - ( e + f + g + h ) / 2
rotatedqy = -c + ( e - f + g - h ) / 2
rotatedqz = -d + ( e - f - g + h ) / 2

Result = Quaternion(rotatedq0, rotatedqx, rotatedqy, rotatedqz)
```

Now I'll focus on the coordinate aspect of this transformation.